# Install PHP Packages On Linux

Tags: php, linux, unix, php-7

I have Php 7.3 installed and I am trying to install the below packages but I am getting an error "No Package available". Can someone please help?

Command
sudo  yum install php73-common php73-cli php73-gd php73-gd php73-mysqlnd php73-ldap php73-soap php73-mbstring

Error

```
No package php73-common available.
No package php73-cli available.
No package php73-gd available.
No package php73-gd available.
No package php73-mysqlnd available.
No package php73-ldap available.
No package php73-soap available.
No package php73-mbstring available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Remi's PHP7.3 repository first

```
sudo yum-config-manager ––enable remi–php73
sudo yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql –y
```

You can update the packages as per your requirement.

Here is a detail [doc](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-php-7-on-centos)

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I got the below error when I executed the enable remi command "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/misc.py:133: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal"  .I did a yum update and tried but same error

Comment: this installation may fail if you have extensions that are not compatible with PHP 7.3. This seems to be a Python issue try to upgrade your python.

Comment: For PHP, for proper configuration of "remi" repository, see the Wizard instructions: php-laminas-feed-2.15.0-1.fc35

Comment: For the YUM issue try using C locale: LANG=C yum ...

Comment: enabled the remi php7.3 .. but i get the below error for some packages .eg sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm   "No package oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm available.
No package oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm available."

Comment: That is a separate issue that is not PHP extension as PHP extensions start with the prefix of PHP. if your issue is resolved mark the solution as useful/accepted.